# How do I prevent the screen reader from saying "group" when reading this div tag's text?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

On my web page, I have a `div` (shown below), which has text in it that I want to be read by a screen reader.

**HTML**

```
<div tabIndex={0}>
    "text needs to be read"
</div>
```

I can hear the text is read without even providing the aria-label. However, I heard "text needs to be read group". I would like to know how can I avoid it saying "group"? I did not put a group role for the div tag.

### Another example

This is another example that describes the problem much cleaner

```
<span class="jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-text-live" tabindex="-1" data-clicked="true">Live</span>
```

Run the above snippet in any browser. It makes the screen readers to announce it as "Live, group". 
Is there any way to mitigate this behaviour. Expected behaviour should be like the screen readers should read it as "Live"

Comment: Which screen reader software & version are you're using to read your screen? That would allow people to try a screen reader out, to listen to what you're hearing.

Comment: I am using Edge + Narrator.

Comment: @bunny Did you fixed this? I want to know the fix please

Answer (score 6):

Lots of things going on here.

First of all, **all** text on a webpage is available to a screen reader and does not need `tabindex="0"` to make it available to be read.  Screen readers provide [lots of shortcut keys](https://support.freedomscientific.com/training/Surfs-Up/Quick_Keys.htm) to navigate to different types of elements (headings, tables, lists, etc).  For elements that don't have a direct navigation key, the screen reader user can use the up/down arrow keys to walk the [accessibility tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/#intro_treetypes) (similar to the DOM).

Secondly, regarding `tabindex="0"`, it should only be set on **interactive** elements.  The [tabindex spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute) says:

> authors should only make elements focusable if they act as interactive controls or widgets. In addition, authors should ensure that these focusable elements have an appropriate ARIA role attribute.

And regarding ARIA roles in the second sentence in the spec quote, if your element **does** receive focus, if it's not a natively focusable element (such as a `<a>` or `<button>` or `<input>`), then it needs to have an appropriate [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) so that the screen reader user will know how to interact with it.

And related to this, you mentioned [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label).  The `aria-label` is only honored on elements that have an appropriate role. See "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)".

So given all that, it's a little difficult to answer your question because your simple example is not specific enough.  A `<div>` without a role should not read as "group".  Group is usually `role="region"` (or `<section>`).  The behavior you're hearing may depend on what browser you're using, what screen reader, how you're navigating in with the screen reader (<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>arrow</kbd> or quicknav key).

Comment: I see. I delete the tabIndex and I have no problem with it using NVDA with Chrome. However, if I use Edge + Narrator, the screen reader is not able to read text in the div if I use either tab or arrow. What kind of role I should give to the div so that the narrator can read it? The div just contains some information in the header of the web application.

Comment: A more complete code example would help.  If the <div> is embedded in a <header> (which has an implicit `role="banner"`), you shouldn't need anything else.  You're using the down arrow in narrator to walk the DOM?  And it skips over the <div>?  Do you have `aria-hidden="true"` anywhere?

Comment: @slugolicious I have a similar problem, my save button inside header is reading as save button banner . How to avoid saying banner

Comment: A `<header>` has a default landmark role of *"banner"*.  When you navigate to the first element in a landmark, it'll announce the landmark type as well as the label of the element.  All following elements within the header won't repeat *"banner"*.  Is your button the first thing in your header?

Comment: @slugolicious yes, it is announcing for the first element . Can we avoid this problem ?

Comment: It’s not a “problem”. That’s exactly what the screen reader should say. All you can do is move the button outside the `<header>`